# Convert (American) negative numbers to -Europeans with Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting data from an American system. The numbers what I get in the CSV are strings "(100)" and I have to convert it to -100 integer. I have **N number of columns** in the data frame and i have to do it for all the columns.

What I am doing now is that I replace all the parenthesis to empty and to negative value sign. This is not the best solution as it is converting all the given values in the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('American.csv',  thousands=r',')

df=df.apply(lambda z: z.astype(str).str.replace(')',''))
df=df.apply(lambda z: z.astype(str).str.replace('(','-'))
```

**What I expect:**

```
"(100)" -> -100

"Nick (Jones)" ->"Nick **(Jones)**"
```

**What I get:**

```
"(100)" -> -100

"Nick (Jones)" ->"Nick **-Jones**"
```

I would need a code that does the necessary conversion with the numbers for all columns but does not bother with other values.

Comment: Pleazs share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There's no American vs European system for negative numbers. Everyone uses `-` followed by digits. Some *accounting reports* though use `()` to represent negative values.

Comment: maybe creat function which checks if first char is `(` and then it replace others or slice first and last char to get only number. Eventually you could check aslo if last char is `)` and if rest `isdigit()`

Comment: `df=df.apply(lambda z: z.astype(str).str.replace('(','-') if z.astype(str).str.isdigit == True else z.astype(str).str.replace('(','')) `  something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["(100)", "Nick (Jones)"])
new_df = df.replace('\((\d+)\)', '-\\1',regex=True)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
              0
0          -100
1  Nick (Jones)
```

Regex:

[image]

Captures any number of digits inside the pair of brackets (Group #1), and put `-` in front of it (-Group #1).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a converter for the numeric columns while reading the data?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos AFAIK, to use `converters` one needs to know the index of desired columns beforehand. Besides, there's a possibility that some columns have mixed values of such _negative ints_ and string with parenthesis, just as demonstrated.